# How to delete an item from a Dictonary using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I need to delete a specific item from a dictonary..

The dictonary is like

```
      dict["Key1"]="Value1"
      dict["Key2"]="Value2"
      dict["Key3"]="Value3"
      dict["Key4"]="Value2"
```

How to delete the item if another item has the same value using LINQ

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which item do you want to delete, the item with Key2 or the one with Key4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here my tested solution:

```
dict.GroupBy(x => x.Value, x => x.Key)
.Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
.SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1))
.ToList().ForEach(x => dict.Remove(x))
```

Comment: This answer is actually clever. Didn't know about the GroupBy that takes a "select this" parameter.

Answer (score 3):

check orginal answer by @Jon Skeet : [C#: Remove duplicate values from dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462101/c-remove-duplicate-values-from-dictionary)

```
var uniqueValues = myDict.GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)
                         .Select(group => group.First())
                         .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dupKeys = dict.GroupBy(innerD => innerD.Value)
                .Where(mergedByValue => mergedByValue.Count() > 1)
                .Select(mergedByValue => mergedByValue.OrderByDescending(m => m.Key).First().Key);

dict.Where(d => dupKeys.Contains(d.Key)).ToList()
  .ForEach(d => dict.Remove(d.Key));
```

This assumes you want the *last* duplicate removed, where last is defined as the last ordinal string value.

If you want *all* duplicates removed, change your dupKeys to this:

```
var dupKeys = dict.GroupBy(innerD => innerD.Value)
                .Where(mergedByValue => mergedByValue.Count() > 1).Dump()
                .SelectMany(mergedByValue => mergedByValue.Select(m => m.Key));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx).

Comment: @ Incognito: Thank you... you are correct but i need to remove the duplicates after creating the dictonary.

Comment: & Pramodh, You are not correct, distinct will not help you filter a collection based on a property of the objects and still use associated properties.

Comment: Have you checked the link. This is not SQL distinct. You can use it on existing dictionary.

Comment: yes? now try and use it to get the keys of all distinct values.

Comment: @Graphain I agree it gives you way to get distinct values easily.