# Merging dictionaries in key level and then in value level

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have two dictionaries like

```
Dictionary<String, String> one = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "A", "1" },
    { "B", "2" },
    { "C", "3" },
    { "D", "4" },
    { "E", "5" },
    { "F", "6" },
    { "G", "7" },
    { "H", "8" }
};

Dictionary<String, String> two = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "A", "1" },
    { "B", "2" },
    { "C", "3" },
    { "E", "4" },
    { "F", "4" },
    { "I", "6" },
    { "J", "10" },
    { "K", "11" }
};
```

i need to merge the two dictionary in key level and then in value level and to add the resulting dictionary into the new dictionary `three`, the resulting dictionary should not have same keys or same values and in this case the resulting dictionary is like

```
Dictionary<String, String> three = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "A", "1" },
    { "B", "2" },
    { "C", "3" },
    { "D", "4" },
    { "E", "5" },
    { "F", "6" },
    { "G", "7" },
    { "H", "8" },
    { "J", "10" },
    { "K", "11" }
};
```

Now i'm using like

1. Union all the keys in the two dictionaries
2. Creating a new dictionary with the new keys
3. removing the dupicate values( same values )

**EDIT**: if both the dictionaries having same key value pair then i need to store the the key value pair from the first dictionary .

is there any way to do this using LINQ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: When the keys match in both the dictionaries, you want to store the value in the first dictionary as you have done for F, 6 ?

Comment: yes. if both the dictionaries having same key value pair then i need to store the the key value pair from the first dictionary

Comment: You need to specify the collision-resolution rules more precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, using the fact that a dictionary is a sequence of key/value pairs:

```
var dictionary = dictionary1.Concat(dictionary2)
                            .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
                            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First());
```

That's not terribly efficient, admittedly (as it essentially builds up a hash table twice) but I believe it will work.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: thank you , i need to remove the duplicate values from "dictionary". As i mentioned, the resulting dictionary should not contain same key or same value

Comment: @Pramodh: See my answer where distinct takes place

Comment: Jon, could you please describe what for `ToLookup()` have you used?

Comment: @abatishchev: It allows there to be multiple entries with the same key. We then just take the first of those values when constructing the dictionary.

Comment: @Pramodh: What exactly do you mean by "same key or same value"? Please give a concrete example of what you want to happen which my code doesn't satisfy.

Comment: With the above LINQ the result is like 
{ "A", "1" },

 { "B", "2" }, { "C", "3" }, { "D", "4" }, { "E", "5" }, { "F", "6" }, { "G", "7" }, { "Z", "3" }, { "X", "4" }, { "I", "6" }, { "H", "8" }, { "J", "10" }, { "K", "11" } i need to remove the entries of "Z" "X" and "I"

Comment: i got a solution from ur answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462101/c-remove-duplicate-values-from-dictionary). Thank you

Comment: The LINQ is like     



one.Concat(two)
                             .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
                             .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First()).GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)
                             .Select(group => group.First())
                             .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

Comment: @Pramodh: Where do Z, X and I come in? They're not in your sample source data. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and think about what readers will need to know when you write questions.

Comment: oh sorry... not  Z,X, I.... only I.   F and I have same values. i need to remove I from the "dictionary".

Comment: @Pramodh: So why remove I rather than F? Don't forget that a dictionary isn't inherently ordered...

Comment: @ Jon Skeet : if the both the dictionaries having same keys the i'll keep the first dictionary key.and if both the dictionaries having same values i need to store the value from the first dictionary to the result.

the expected answer is like



{ "A", "1" }, 
    { "B", "2" }, 
    { "C", "3" }, 
    { "D", "4" }, 
    { "E", "5" }, 
    { "F", "6" }, 
    { "G", "7" }, 
    { "H", "8" }, 
    { "J", "10" }, 
    { "K", "11" }

Comment: @Pramodh: What if one dictionary has the same value for two keys which aren't in the other dictionary?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: in that case too i need to keep only the first value

Comment: @Pramodh: There's no such concept as "first" in a dictionary. It's an *unordered* collection of key/value pairs.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet : i meant the first entry. and i din't know that dictionary is an Unordered collection. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
var three = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(var kvp in two.Concat(one))
  three[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
```

This is quite efficient, but I'm not sure if this is the output you want; the problem statement is not clear enough.

**EDIT**: If you want to subsequently remove duplicate *values* from `three`:

```
var keysWithDuplicateValues = three.ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Value, kvp => kvp.Key)
                                   .SelectMany(group => group.Skip(1))
                                   .ToList();

foreach(var key in keysWithDuplicateValues)
   three.Remove(key);
```

Note that this is better than eagerly removing duplicate keys *and* duplicate values at the start, because some of the collisions may be automatically resolved.

Answer (score 1):

A linq-only method would be to concatenate the two dictionaries and fold the resulting sequence of key/values into a single result. This will overwrite the values for any keys in `dict2` that are also in `dict1`:

```
var dict3 = dict2.Concat(dict1)
    .Aggregate(new Dictionary<string, string>(), (d, kvp) => {
        d[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
        return d;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class StringKeyValuePairEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<string, string> x, KeyValuePair<string, string> y)
    {
        return x.Key == y.Key;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<string, string> obj)
    {
        return obj.Key.GetHashCode();
    }
}

var three = Enumerable.Concat(one, two)
                .Distinct(new StringKeyValuePairEqualityComparer())
                .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);

int count = three.Keys.Count; // 11
```