# How to remove duplicate combinations from a List<string> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates

I'm having a List of String like

```
List<string> MyList = new List<string>
{ 
    "A-B", 
    "B-A", 
    "C-D", 
    "C-E", 
    "D-C",
    "D-E",
    "E-C",
    "E-D",
    "F-G",
    "G-F"
};
```

I need to remove duplicate from the List i.e, if "A-B" and "B-A" exist then i need to keep only "A-B" (First entry)

So the result will be like

```
"A-B"   
"C-D"
"C-E"   
"D-E"
"F-G"
```

Is there any way to do this using LINQ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634335/merging-dictionaries-in-key-level-and-then-in-value-level

Comment: Will each string always be exactly 3 characters?

Comment: @ Mark Byres : No , it can be more than three characters

Comment: @Pramodh: Will the list always be sorted initially?

Comment: @ Mark Bayers : Never , it will not be in order

Comment: @Pramodh: is it a requirement that the output is sorted?

Comment: @ Fredrik Mörk : need not be in order

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This returns the sequence you look for:

```
var result = MyList
    .Select(s => s.Split('-').OrderBy(s1 => s1))
    .Select(a => string.Join("-", a.ToArray()))
    .Distinct();

foreach (var str in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

In short: split each string on the `-` character into two-element arrays. Sort each array, and join them back together. Then you can simply use `Distinct` to get the unique values.

Update: when thinking a bit more, I realized that you can easily remove one of the `Select` calls:

```
var result = MyList
    .Select(s => string.Join("-", s.Split('-').OrderBy(s1 => s1).ToArray()))
    .Distinct();
```

Disclaimer: this solution will always keep the value "A-B" over "B-A", regardless of the order in which the appear in the original sequence.

Comment: Downvoters, please leave a comment so any errors can be corrected.

Comment: +1, minor quibble though.  The `Distinct` method is defined as returning an unordered collection so to be 100% correct you'd need to sort the result to get the ordered specified by the OP.  Then again it's implemented as an ordered collection so it's at best a nitpick.

Answer (score 14):

Implement IEqualityComparer witch returns true on Equals("A-B", "B-A"). And use [Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) method

Comment: Example of IEqualityComparer  implementation will bring you an answer approval ;)

Comment: @abatischev: I don't know - giving an IEqualityComparer imlpementation would feel like doing someone else's homework...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`Enumerable.Distinct(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEqualityComparer<TSource>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) overload.

Now you just need to implement [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx). Here's something for you to get started:

```
class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<String>
{

    public bool Equals(String s1, String s2)
    {
        // will need to test for nullity
        return Reverse(s1).Equals(s2);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(String s)
    {
        // will have to implement this
    }

}
```

For a `Reverse()` implementation, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string-in-c-2-0)

Comment: This assumes that the bits before and after the `-` are always single characters (or that you want palindromic equality). The asker has indicated that this assumption does not hold. If you fix the answer, I’ll upvote. (While you’re at it, in the interest of good education, please give it a more descriptive name than simply “Comparer”.)

Answer (score 1):

Very basic, but could be written better (but it's just working):

```
class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
  {
      public bool Equals(string x, string y)
      {
          return (x[0] == y[0] && x[2] == y[2]) || (x[0] == y[2] && x[2] == y[0]);
      }

      public int GetHashCode(string obj)
      {
          return 0;
      }
  }

var MyList = new List<String>
{ 
    "A-B", 
    "B-A", 
    "C-D", 
    "C-E", 
    "D-C",
    "D-E",
    "E-C",
    "E-D",
    "F-G",
    "G-F"
}
.Distinct(new Comparer());

foreach (var s in MyList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: There's a subtle bug: if you run the debugger, you should notice that E-C equals E-D using your code, which is incorrect...

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the IEqualityComparer like this:

```
public class CharComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<string> Members

    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == y)
            return true;

        if (x.Length == 3 && y.Length == 3)
        {
            if (x[2] == y[0] && x[0] == y[2])
                return true;

            if (x[0] == y[2] && x[2] == y[0])
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        // return 0 to force the Equals to fire (otherwise it won't...!)
        return 0;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The sample program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> MyList = new List<string>
        { 
            "A-B", 
            "B-A", 
            "C-D", 
            "C-E", 
            "D-C",
            "D-E",
            "E-C",
            "E-D",
            "F-G",
            "G-F"
        };

        var distinct = MyList.Distinct(new CharComparer());
        foreach (string s in distinct)
            Console.WriteLine(s);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The result:

```
"A-B"   
"C-D"
"C-E"   
"D-E"
"F-G"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int checkID = 0;
while (checkID < MyList.Count)
{
 string szCheckItem = MyList[checkID];
 string []Pairs = szCheckItem.Split("-".ToCharArray());
 string szInvertItem = Pairs[1] + "-" + Pairs[0];
 int i=checkID+1;
 while (i < MyList.Count)
 {
  if((MyList[i] == szCheckItem) || (MyList[i] == szInvertItem))
  {
   MyList.RemoveAt(i);
   continue;
  }
  i++;
 }

 checkID++;
}
```