# Remove duplicate lists from a parent list using hashset in c#

Tags: c#, hashset

I have a parent `List` which contains several child `Lists`. And these inner `Lists` contain `Column` objects.

```
List<List<Column>> listOfAllColumns;

public class Column
{
    public string SectionName;
    public string StirrupType;
    public int StirrupSize;
    public double StirrupSpacing;
}
```

Let's say my child `Lists` contain different `Column` objects like this:

```
List1 = {c1, c1, c2}
List2 = {c1, c2, c1}
List3 = {c2, c3}
List4 = {c1,c1, c2}
```

And the parent `List` contains these `Lists`:

```
listOfAllColumns = {List1, List2, List3, List4}
```

Now I want a method that removes duplicate lists from the listOfAllColumns list. For example, it will look into the list above and remove list4.

```
List1: c1,c1,c2
List2: c1,c2,c1
List3: c2,c3
List4: c1,c1,c2 (it is equal to List1 so it is a duplicate)
```

I know this can be done using `Linq` and `Distinct` method but I want to do it using `Hashset`.

- By the way the order is important, so for example {c1, c2, c1} is different than {c2,c1,c1}.

**Update 1:**

Here is the tricky part. The order is important inside the child lists but it is not important in the parent list. So List1:{c1, c2} and List2: {c2,c1} are different but it is not important how they are added to the `Parent List`, so listOfAllColumns:{List1, List2} and listOfAllColumns:{List2,Lis1} are the same thing.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
Column c1 = new Column() { SectionName = "C50", StirrupType = "Tie" };
Column c2 = new Column() { SectionName = "C50", StirrupType = "Spiral" };
Column c3 = new Column() { SectionName = "C40", StirrupType = "Tie" };


List<Column> list1 = new List<Column>() { c1, c1, c2 };
List<Column> list2 = new List<Column>() { c1, c2, c1 };
List<Column> list3 = new List<Column>() { c2, c3 };
List<Column> list4 = new List<Column>() { c1, c1, c2 };


List<List<Column>> listOfAllColumns = new List<List<Column>>() { list1, list2, list3, list4 };


HashSet<List<Column>> hs = new HashSet<List<Column>>();
List<List<Column>> uniquelistOfAllColumns = new List<List<Column>>();

foreach (var c in listOfAllColumns)
{
    if (hs.Add(c))
    {
        // my logic is that hashset should recognize the duplicates in this part.
        uniquelistOfAllColumns.Add(c);
    }
}
```

A similar question here:
[C#: Remove duplicate values from dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462101/c-remove-duplicate-values-from-dictionary)

Comment: Hashset has no order, so if order matters using it, is a nonsense

Comment: Why not use LINQ?  Its a perfect fit for this problem.

Comment: @Blau Here is the tricky part. The order is important inside the child lists but it is not important in the parent list. So List1:{c1, c2} and List2: {c2,c1} are different but it is not important how they are added to the Parent List, so listOfAllColumns:{List1, List2} and listOfAllColumns:{List2,Lis1} are the same thing. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should override your `HashSet` methods `Contains` and `Equals` (where you can implement the ordered checking).

Then Insert into your implementation of `HashSet` from you parentList. You will check if the `HashSet`contains `List<column>` and insert if its not there.

But `Linq` seems to be the best solution.

Comment: You can reuse [this OrderedSet class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17853085/122195)

Comment: @Dexters I included the code I've been trying to implement.

Comment: @Vahid what you are trying to do will work, but you need to implement your own HashSet Contains and Equals routines..

Comment: @Dexters Thanks. Can you give me a link to an example of implementing these?

Comment: @Dexter Did you look at the link I provided in the question? I wonder why the Hashset method works when we add 'string' types but when we add 'List<Object>' types, we can't by default.