# How to find duplicate values in List<Dictionary<string, object>>?

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have a List of `Dictionary<string, object>`.
How to find duplicate values in all dictionaries by value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: Remove duplicate values from dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462101/c-remove-duplicate-values-from-dictionary)

Comment: posible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172394/finding-duplicate-values-in-dictionary-and-print-key-of-the-duplicate-element

Comment: He's asking for finding duplicates in a `List` of `Dictionaries`. Those aren't exact duplicates.

Comment: Duplicates within a dictionary or any duplicate value?

Comment: doctor, duplicates in List of dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks guys! That helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can find duplicate values with their occurrences using LINQ.
It gives you duplicate values and its occurrences (index in list and key in dictionary).

```
var duplicates = dicList
    .SelectMany((x, i) => x.Select(p => new { Index = i, Key = p.Key, Value = p.Value }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => new
        {
            Value = x.First().Value,
            Occurrences  = x.Select(o => new { Index = o.Index, Key = o.Key })
        });
```

If you just want duplicate values then use simplified version

```
var duplicates = listOfDic
    .SelectMany(x => x.Values)
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use linq for compact code:

```
       List<Dictionary<string, object>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        list.SelectMany(dictionary => dictionary.Values).GroupBy(d => d).Where(x => x.Count() >1);
```

Comment: This works only with one dictionary. But not with a List.

Answer (score 1):

Old classic loop

```
var uniqueValues = new HashSet<object>();
var duplicateValues = new List<object>();
foreach (var value in yourDictionaries.SelectMany(dict => dict.Values))
{
    if (uniqueValues.Add(value) == false)
    {
        duplicateValues.Add(value);
    }
}
```

`SelectMany` is a key method for getting all values of all dictionaries.

If you are fan of LINQ you can convert it to the LINQ expression for example by using `Aggregate` or `GroupBy`